# Image, Audio & Video upload issues with iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am facing some issues with the image, audio and video upload as well as downloads. So i want to ask some queries here and hoping someone will defiantly gave answers of these queries...

1. I am uploading images, which are taken with the inbuilt iphone 4G camera. We needs quality images with the maximum size. So I am not compressing images and tried to upload with there original size and its taking more then 60 seconds to upload the single image.  I am encoding image data to Base64 before uploading to server.Is this a concern?
2. I am also recording audio & video which could be anything in size. I have encoded audio/video data with Base64 encoding and then uploaded to the server. But it is also taking a lot of time to upload the audio/video.

Please suggest me what would be best for uploading quality images and audio/video to the server with minimum time.

I have implemented Threads,  So the UI will not be hanged while we are uploading/downloading audio/video as well as images. Base64 encoding is the reason for delay in uploads?

Answer (score 0):

The duration of the upload is a function of your network. If you have a slow network it will be a slow upload. You can't improve this without sending less data.